# File generated by plugin not in final jar: why?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Environment: Ubuntu 64bit, maven 3.0.4.

**EDIT**: I have found a way, see answer below; but monkey patching is an epitomy of good design compared to what I came up with...

I use [this plugin](https://github.com/francisdb/serviceloader-maven-plugin) to find implementations of an interface for use with the JDK's [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

I am no maven specialist at all, and I face a problem which I don't know how to solve... While the plugin runs (see output below), the file it generates does not show up in the generated jar :( But it *does* how in `target/classes`!

I have tried and googled quite a bit around, broke my pom many times and I'm now at a complete loss as to how to solve this problem. How should I modify the build section of my pom.xml below to make it work?

```
<!-- In case it matters: <packaging>bundle</packaging> -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <links>
                    <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api</link>
                    <link>http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc</link>
                    <link>http://fge.github.io/msg-simple</link>
                    <link>http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc</link>
                    <link>http://fge.github.com/btf</link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>eu.somatik.serviceloader-maven-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <services>
                    <param>com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider</param>
                </services>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Output (stripped of the irrelevant parts):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building uri-template 0.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- serviceloader-maven-plugin:1.0.2:generate (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Scanning generated classes for implementations...
[INFO] Generating service file /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes/META-INF/services/com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider
[INFO]   + com.github.fge.uritemplate.URITemplateMessageBundle
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@31c480e8
Tests run: 513, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.402 sec

Results :

Tests run: 513, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle (default-bundle) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO]
# Stripped javadoc build messages
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting under `META-INF` in the jar?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot other than what Maven normally generates, no, nothing at all... That is, `MANIFEST.MF`, `pom.properties` and `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found an answer.

But it is UGLY. Like in, a troll looks better than that. So, if you know of a better way, I'm all ears.

What is used is the Maven antrun plugin; I ensure it is executed *after* the jar plugin, and I update the jar so as to add the META-INF/services/xxxx file to it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <links>
                    <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api</link>
                    <link>http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc</link>
                    <link>http://fge.github.io/msg-simple</link>
                    <link>http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc</link>
                    <link>http://fge.github.com/btf</link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="jarname"
                                value="${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                            <property name="victim"
                                value="${project.build.directory}/${jarname}"/>
                            <property name="serviceFile"
                                value="${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/services/${serviceName}"/>
                            <echo>${victim}</echo>
                            <echo>${serviceFile}</echo>
                            <jar destfile="${victim}" update="true">
                                <zipfileset file="${serviceFile}"
                                    prefix="META-INF/services/"/>
                            </jar>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle-create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>eu.somatik.serviceloader-maven-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <services>
                    <param>${serviceName}</param>
                </services>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried various things, including the maven shade plugin which doesn't work, and many other things I cannot remember...